# Lua graphics display on an existing window

Tags: lua

I want to display graphics on top of an existing window, is that possible using pure Lua? because i cannot find the stuff i need, i only found how to display graphics in an specific OpenGL window.

I've looked to some code posted on github

https://github.com/ittner/lua-gd/tree/master

https://github.com/stetre/moongl

https://github.com/vrld/G4L

that's all i've found

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do it in pure Lua, as it doesn't provide any platform-specific drawing/GUI methods. It's possible to use some library (like those you've listed), but I'm not familiar with them. You can probably use [wxlua](https://github.com/pkulchenko/wxlua), which is a wrapper around wxwidgets and provides `SetTransparent` method on its `wxFrame` object and ways to draw on a surface with transparent background or transparent brush (you can set the degree of transparency). You still need to find the position of the window you are interested in (to cover it with your window) and this is going to be system-dependent. For example, on Windows you can do this by using [winapi window functions](http://stevedonovan.github.io/winapi/api.html#Class_Window).